# start timeCircles plugin in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to start timeCircles plugin in bootstrap modal window.
here is plugin: http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/index.html
loading data in modal body from server and starting timeCircles in there `$(".mytimer").TimeCircles();`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mymodal").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
        var link = $(e.relatedTarget);
        $(this).find(".modal-body").load('/load-from-link/');
        $(".mytimer").TimeCircles();
    });
```

in the HTML loaded from server I place something like this and another data:

```
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="mytimer" data-timer="{{timer:seconds}}"></div>
        </div>
```

But this is not work. But if I try to start it manually from browser console printing there this: `$(".mytimer").TimeCircles();` it works and timer starts. Please tell me where I made mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to put some timeout ?

```html
$("#mymodal").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
  var link = $(e.relatedTarget);
  $(this).find(".modal-body").load('/load-from-link/');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(".mytimer").TimeCircles();
  }, 100);
});
```

Hope it was helpful !

Comment: Thank you Bertrand, it works! It seams TimeCircles starting before ajax complete, right? Is there any way to make this without timeout, to wait when ajax complete?

Comment: You're welcome ! You have an ajax event called onAjaxComlete ([link](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)), but I always use a timeout when I open modals. I think the real problem is that the event show.bs.modal is triggered just before the modal is opened, so the line with ".mytimer" doesn't find anything.